# Angular Draggable Directive with Lines

Tags: angularjs, draw, directive

I'm currently attempting to draw lines between a draggable directive but I'm having trouble figuring out how to draw a line in the first place. My code to draw a line:

```
var ctx = element[0].getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.stroke();
```

(This was taken from another website)

Right now my compiler complains that: element[0].getContext is not a function

My Question: Is there another directive that I can use that has built in lines and boxes that I can drag or link up? OR what should I be doing instead to draw lines?

Comment: Your element should be canvas.

Comment: How do i extract the canvas?

Comment: If i want the canvas to be the entire document?